# Typescript create Object copy with all key properties but different type

Tags: typescript

I have a question regarding the types I need to use to obtain the following:

```js
type keys = "foo" | "bar";

type Type1 = Record<keys, number>;
// Using `keyof Type1` just in case :)
type Type2 = Record<keyof Type1, boolean>;

// Created somewhere, we just have this
const foo: Type1 = {
  foo: 0,
  bar: 3
};

// How do I create a `Type2` object without manually specifying all the props?
// Given that I have all the needed keys in foo?
const bar: Type2 = ???
```

I have already tried with a couple of times with `Object.assign` and object spread without any result nice.

```js
// `number` not assignable to boolean
const bar: Type2 = { ...foo }; // not working
const bar: Type2 = Object.assign({}, foo); // not working
// Not working as expected, type is `Type1 & Type2`
const bar = Object.assign({} as Type2, foo); // not working
// Working but a bit ugly no?
const bar: Type2 = Object.assign({} as Type2, foo); // Working
```

The implementation should be inside a function that maps from `Type1` to `Type2` like:

```js
const foonction = (obj: Type1): Type2 => {
  // create object and map values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Type2` is already has the same keys as `Type1` so all you have to do is to map properties, which are part of objects and not types. So your `foonction` may look like this

```
const foonction = (obj: Type1): Type2 => {
    let res = <Type2>{}; 
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => res[key as keyof Type2] = obj[key as keyof Type1] != 0);  // Do your mapping here
    return res;
}
```

`Object.assign` will produce result of type `Type1 & Type2` ([intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)). So you'll not do mapping, you'll have object `bar` containing the same properties of the same type as `foo`.